# Installing Ubuntu after Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

How can I install Ubuntu on Windows 10 as dual boot? I have a DVD with Ubuntu and when I tried to install Ubuntu I had a warning that the hard disk will be erased. How can I install Ubuntu and keep my Windows 10?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably don't want to erase your Windows.

First step would be not to follow recommended steps during Ubuntu installation, and choose **custom** one.

I would recommend first to create partition in windows boot for linux, don't place it in the middle and non less than 50GB (despite the fact that Linux is light weight, it never cleans it's garbage, so with 50GB you will not have to clean it for next year or 2). Once you have partition for linux, at this point you can start instaling Ubuntu.

During custome instalation set SWAP area on linux partition to your RAM size, everething else to Ubuntu ROOT and linux formating (should have number 4 at the end), **and under root I mean '/'**.

Before proceeding it will show you what change will be applied.

Something to note: 
`Ubuntu will take you BIOS time, thus on Windows you'll be 1 hours late`
and `if eventually you would want to roll back to solo windows boot it's not straightforward`.

Answer (score 0):

well, Ubuntu has a grub in it which allows you to dual boot after installing ubuntu just select your hard disk which you boot from. The bootloader will be installed there. make sure you install Ubuntu and windows on the same hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

To get dual boot on your system, check out this link [dual boot windows and Ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) and once you have followed the steps properly, ensure that you do make an entry for Ubuntu OS in your grub.

To do so, simply follow the below steps:

- Boot into `Windows` OS
- Combine `Windows` + `r` keys together and type `cmd` to open command prompt **(You do not require any admin rights to execute the below command)**
- Once you are in command prompt window, type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit the `Enter` key

As soon as the command gets executed, reboot your system and you will be asked to choose either of the two OS i.e., either `Windows` or `Ubuntu` on every startup.